# Eclipse Juno XML auto-complete

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-juno

yesterday I installed the new Eclipse Juno and noticed one thing: while editing an XML document (e.g. layout file), it doesn't show me the list of possible options after typing "android: " which Eclipse Indigo always did. That was really helpful since it saves time by long commands and helps if you are not sure what options are possible. Is there a way to fix that? Thanks

Comment: that is a common problem and its a little weird too-- i am also experiencing the same

Comment: Is this related at all to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=247312 ?

Comment: Which editor are you using (you have more than one if ADT is installed)?  It might make a difference.

Comment: Android Common XML Editor. The thing is that I have (almost) the same version of Eclipse Juno at home (Win 7 x64) and at college (Win 7 x32). When I'm at college everything (incl. the auto-complete) is working fine. When I'm at home the XML auto-complete  doesn't work o_0